# What is the most efficient way to add a special character after a sequence of repeated elements in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
lst= [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5]
```

I need to prepare a list in this format

```
lst = [1,1,$,2,2,$,3,3,$,4,4,$,5,5,5]
```

This is the function I have used to form pairs of elements and add a special character when the pairs are not equal. This approach works well when the list size is small, but when bigger lists are considered, this is not the most efficient way.

[image: Attached image]

Also, is there a way where we can keep a track of the indices we are adding the special character at? Like maintaining another list just for the index values.

Comment: Please always add your code as a code block to your question rather than with a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` and `chain` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
out = list(chain.from_iterable(list(g)+['$'] for _,g in groupby(lst)))[:-1]
```

output:

```
[1, 1, '$', 2, 2, '$', 3, 3, '$', 4, 4, '$', 5, 5, 5]
```

input:

```
lst = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5]
```

*NB. do **NOT** use `list` as variable name, this shadows the `list` python builtin*

###### alternative using a generator

```
def add_symbol(lst, symbol='$'):
    if lst:
        prev = lst[0]
    for item in lst:
        if item != prev:
            yield symbol
        prev = item
        yield item
            
out = list(add_symbol(lst))
```

###### getting the insertion indices as side effect

```
def add_symbol(lst, symbol='$', indices=None):
    if lst:
        prev = lst[0]
    insertions = 0
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item != prev:
            yield symbol
            if isinstance(indices, list):
                insertions += 1
                indices.append(i+insertions)
        prev = item
        yield item

idx = []
out = list(add_symbol(lst, indices=idx))

print(idx)
[3, 6, 9, 12]

print(out)
[1, 1, '$', 2, 2, '$', 3, 3, '$', 4, 4, '$', 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: This creates a list with '$' at the end of the list as well.

Comment: @butragueno not if you use the code in the current form (I made an early edit)

Comment: Just for funsies, avoid temporary `list`s per group with `out = list(chain.from_iterable(chain(g, '$') for _, g in groupby(lst)))[:-1]` Note that two-lining it would be more efficient if the output is huge (removing the `[:-1]` and adding a second line that just does `del out[-1:]` which just removes the final element, if any, rather than copying all but one element to another `list`).

Comment: Thanks for this. This works perfectly. Also, is there a way where we can keep a track of the indices we are adding a the special character at? Like maintaining another list just for the index values.

Comment: Yes, but this won't be very pythonic with those two approaches (it's better not to add side effects in list comprehensions/generators). Maybe this should be a follow up question?

Comment: @butragueno: You'd definitely want to do that with the generator function; trying to force it into the listcomp would be ugly. Or, if the separator doesn't appear in your inputs, you just post-process the listcomp: `sep_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(out) if x == '$']`.

Comment: Yes @mozway. It is a follow up query. I have edited the post now. Sorry, I am new to SOF community.

Comment: I rather mean a new question, but I edited the answer ;)

Comment: When I execute the generator code, the insertion is not giving the expected list, could you check it once more? This is output I am getting [1, 1, 2, '$', 2, 3, '$', 3, 4, '$', 4, 5, '$', 5, 5]

Comment: I'm afraid, It is still the same.

Comment: damn I needed coffee, I moved the wrong `yield` :p